# Two divs in the same row even after Zoom in or out

Tags: css, html

I have two divs with pretty simple codes here: http://jsfiddle.net/vBngZ/
The codes(HTML):

```
<div class="subcontent" id="div2">
    <div class="orangebox" style="width: 55%;margin-top: 6px;float: left;background-color: red;">
        <div class="title">Shipping</div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item will be shipped from Palestine within 48 hours after receiving full payment, with tracking information that will be provided to you.</li>
            <li>All products are checked and packaged well before dispatch.</li>
            <li>We ship the soap with its Gamila Secret original box.</li>
            <li>We ship worldwide by Palastine postal. This international order may take longer to arrive, Normally the shipment to worldwide is used to take 18 to 35 business days.</li>
            <li>If you have not received your shipment within 35 days from payment, please contact us IMMEDIATELY. We will track the shipment and get back to you as soon as possible with a reply. </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bluebox" style="width: 44.3%;margin-top: 6px;float: right;background-color: blue">
        <div class="title">Payment</div>
        <ul>
            <li>We only accept payments via paypal.</li>
            <li>Payment must be made within 4 days upon auction end, otherwise an unpaid case will be opened</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

One div is taller than the other, and I want both of them to be in the same line/row and in the same height even after zoom-in(CTRL +) and zoom-out(CTRL -), two things I don't want is:
1) not using overflow, so I don't want a scrollbar to appear after zoom-in.
2) I want all the words that inside the paragraph to stay inside it even after zoom-in.
I tried to figure out a solution and I came up with the `display: table-cell` but I don't know how could I use it here.
If there's any other solution please give it to me.

Comment: Avoid putting style in your HTML.

Comment: I will remove it then

Comment: I tried zooming in and out  and its fine.
The browser resizes boxes and font-size. Boxes remain their position, text never appears outside of them.
Tested on Chrom 29, Firefox 23, Opera 12 (not the chromium one as in v15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/vBngZ/2/) with a working solution.

*Best practice*: always separate your styling from your markup.
I took the liberty of separating the relevant styling from the markup, notice how its clearer & cleaner that way.

**Explanation:**

1. set the container (in your case its `.subcontent`) display attribute to `table-row`.
2. set the content `div`s (in your case `.orangebox` & `.bluebox`) display attribute to `table-cell`.
3. remove the float rules from your content `div`s.
4. replace the `margin-top` with `padding-top` if you want to have extra space before the content.

**CSS**

```
.subcontent
{
    display: table-row;
}
.orangebox
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 55%;
    padding-top: 6px;
    background-color: red;
}
.bluebox
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 44.3%;
    padding-top: 6px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: One another question, should I use `.subcontent{display: table-row;}` ?? because I see that it works perfectly without it

Comment: you can omit it if you want.. it's fine. BTW, [here](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html) is a nice article about the display property.

Comment: Thank you for that, one last question, can I make space between the two divs? that's the only thing I'm trying to figure out hardly :(

Comment: I've shorted the `width` of your content `div`s, and add another div between them. also with `display:table-cell;` if you don't specify his width, he will take the remaining space. see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/vBngZ/5/)

Comment: sorry but I can't see any changes with your new fiddle here: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=391661757587979&set=a.288064734614349.71028.100002324738842&type=1&theater

Comment: you meant a space between the `div`s no? look at the `spacer` div I've putted in the middle.. it takes 1% width. your img is not working. upload it to a real image site. like http://imgur.com/

Comment: oh sorry I meant to send: I don't see space between divs in this page http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/vBngZ/5/

Comment: Nevermind, I did it with your idea(adding a 1% width's div between the two divs) Thank you very much for your helpful solutions

Comment: For me it worked even without specifying the 1%. I guess it depends on browsers..